# Loading kendo.timezone in to page

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to use timezone feature provided by Kendo. It is not bundled with `kendo.all.js`. As per documentation I have to include `kendo.timezone.js` into page before using timezone features. **My development environment includes** - fully built `kendo.all.js` and `requirejs`

Now the issue is `kendo.timezone.js` is written as AMD compliant specifying dependency on `./kendo.core` which causes `requirejs` to load `kendo.core.js`. It results into `requirejs` error 'kendo.core.js not present'. To avoid this error either I have to rename my file to `kendo.core.js` or I have to modify `kendo.timezone.js` to depend on `kendo.all.js`.

Which is better of the two solutions(licensing and maintenance problems)? Is there any better way to include `kendo.timezone.js` into my page?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and solved it adding map in the rjs config like this:

```
map: {
    '*': {
        'kendo.core.min': 'kendo'
    }
}
```

It seems to work :)